# Testing Databricks notebook

Tags: docker, unit-testing, testing, pyspark, databricks

I am building a data lake on Databricks. Basically, it consists of a pipeline of Databricks jobs, written in Python (and using PySpark for some). Now, I was wondering how could I test those notebooks.

1. Integration test

As I have experienced, it is really hard to replicate locally the Databricks environment, e.g. PySpark setup. We usually use Docker images to avoid doing such a setup. Databricks has actually a [Docker hub registry](https://hub.docker.com/u/databricksruntime). Did someone already implement integration tests using Docker image ? I can't see many people doing this. The idea would be to test the whole process.

Otherwise, do you know other alternatives to implement integration test in this use case ?

2. Unit test

What is the best practice regarding unit test with Databricks ? I would like to be able to run those unit tests locally. It's more convenient, no ? For now, I have implemented unit tests with pytest for some notebooks that are not using PySpark. It works well. But, testing notebooks that are using PySpark seems much more complex (as the Databricks setup is hard to replicate). What's, according to you, the best practice to unit test databricks notebooks ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are few aspects when it comes to implementing unit & integration tests on Databricks when using Python code, especially notebooks.

- You need to structure code such way that you can load individual functions for testing without need to load full datasets, etc. Although you can use `%run` to include notebooks into other notebooks, but my personal recommendation would be to put code into Python files (not notebooks) that could be loaded as [Python modules](https://docs.databricks.com/en/files/workspace-modules.html) into both notebooks that are doing the actual work, and into unit tests.  If you don't have dependencies on the Databricks-specific functionality, such as, `dbutils`, you can run these tests using the local PySpark.
- It's recommended to run integration tests on Databricks as actual jobs. You can use the [Nutter library](https://github.com/microsoft/nutter) from Microsoft to trigger execution of notebooks or you can just run your pipeline parametrized with pointers to the test datasets instead of full datasets.

Here are some examples of doing unit & integration tests on Databricks:

- [databricks-nutter-repos-demo](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo) - demonstrates how to use Nutter to test notebooks.
- [dlt-files-in-repos-demo](https://github.com/alexott/dlt-files-in-repos-demo) contains code for [blog post about unit & integration testing for Delta Live Tables](https://www.databricks.com/blog/applying-software-development-devops-best-practices-delta-live-table-pipelines), but the techniques described there are applicable to non-DLT pipelines as well.
- [Examples of using different testing libraries with Spark](https://github.com/alexott/spark-playground/tree/master/testing).  My recommendation is to use combination of `chispa` with `pytest-spark`.
- [Official Databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/notebooks/testing.html) on unit testing for notebooks.

I would also recommend to look onto [Databricks Asset Bundles](https://www.databricks.com/resources/demos/tours/data-engineering/databricks-asset-bundles) that simplify deployment of the code, together with its execution.  They are well integrated with [Databricks extension for Visual Studio Code](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/vscode-ext/index.html) that will simplify local development of the code.

Regarding Docker - Databricks Docker images aren't used to run the code, they are used to customize an execution environment, so you can have different libraries and tools pre-installed, but the actual Spark is installed into the Docker container when a job is executed on Databricks.  You can read about that in [the documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/clusters/custom-containers.html) about Docker Container Services.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcouse your can run write things on local for databricks but first you need to understand databricks is cloud only. You can run the pyspark code with databricks-cli installed in your machine.

For testing :

1. You can write test cases for pyspark code using pytest or any other python library

```
pip install databricks-cli # steps to install cli
```